# How do I sense the end of a user scroll of a .Net TrackBar?

Tags: .net, winforms, events, scroll

I have a TrackBar and already have the Scroll event treated, but it may trigger 10 times during a user scroll, and I would like to update a file when the user finishes scrolling. How do I sense the "end of scrolling" ? Would MouseUp and KeyUp do for this purpose ? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be using a ScrollBar for that purpose. The Scroll event on ScrollBar has a ScrollEventArgs, which has a property called Type, one of the values of which is EndScroll.